# Mount Pod Logs to Desired Volume directory

Tags: kubernetes, logging

I am trying to mount my Pod logs directory from `/var/log/pods` to a local node volume `/var/data10`.

Deployment file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:       
   name: nginx-counter
   namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:      
      app: my-nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-nginx
    spec:
       nodeSelector:
         kubernetes.io/hostname: kworker3
       containers:
       - name: count
         image: busybox
         args: [/bin/sh, -c,
            'i=0; while true; do echo "$i: $(date)"; i=$((i+1)); sleep 1; done']
         ports:
         - containerPort: 80
         volumeMounts:
           - name: dirvol
             mountPath: "/var/log/containers"
             readOnly: true
         env:
           - name: POD_NAMESPACE
             valueFrom:
               fieldRef:
                 fieldPath: metadata.namespace
           - name: POD_ID
             valueFrom:
               fieldRef:
                 fieldPath: metadata.uid
           - name: POD_NAME
             valueFrom:
               fieldRef:
                 apiVersion: v1
                 fieldPath: metadata.name
       volumes:
           - name: dirvol
             persistentVolumeClaim:
                     claimName: nginx-pvc
```

PV+PVC file:

```
---
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
    name: nginx-pv
    namespace: default
spec:
  storageClassName: nginx-sc
  capacity:
    storage: 50Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  hostPath:
      path: "/var/data10"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
    name: nginx-pvc
    namespace: default
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
     requests:
         storage: 50Gi
  storageClassName: nginx-sc
---
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
    name: nginx-sc
    namespace: default
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
allowVolumeExpansion: true
---
```

Terminal Window:

```
us@kworker3:~$ cd /var/log/pods/default_nginx-counter-6bdd59f45f-psd9x_f1999c22-6702-41b6-afb7-26db4239977b/
us@kworker3:/var/log/pods/default_nginx-counter-6bdd59f45f-psd9x_f1999c22-6702-41b6-afb7-26db4239977b$ cd count/
us@kworker3:/var/log/pods/default_nginx-counter-6bdd59f45f-psd9x_f1999c22-6702-41b6-afb7-26db4239977b/count$ ls
0.log
us@kworker3:/var/log/pods/default_nginx-counter-6bdd59f45f-psd9x_f1999c22-6702-41b6-afb7-26db4239977b/count$ cd
us@kworker3:~$ 
us@kworker3:~$ 
us@kworker3:~$ 
us@kworker3:~$ cd /var/data10
us@kworker3:/var/data10$ cd default_nginx-counter-6bdd59f45f-psd9x_f1999c22-6702-41b6-afb7-26db4239977b/
us@kworker3:/var/data10/default_nginx-counter-6bdd59f45f-psd9x_f1999c22-6702-41b6-afb7-26db4239977b$ ls
us@kworker3:/var/data10/default_nginx-counter-6bdd59f45f-psd9x_f1999c22-6702-41b6-afb7-26db4239977b$ ls
```

I am trying to take the log file `0.log` and place it in the persistent volume `/var/data10` But as you can see it is empty.

I know I could have used a logging agent like fluentd to grab my container logs but I am trying to use this way to get my logs.

**Please note** that I am trying to apply this scenario for a real web application, kubernetes pods would normally throw logs to the /var/log/containers directory on the node and my goal is to mount the log file (of the container) to the hostDisk (/var/data10) so that when the pod is deleted I would still have the logs inside my volume.

Comment: Can you share your PV and PCV yamls?

Comment: updated to include PV+PVC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symbolic link does not work in hostPath. Use `tee` to make a copy in the pod `echo ... | tee /pathInContainer/app.log` which in turn mount to `/var/data10` hostPath volume. If `tee` is not ideal, your best bet is running a log agent as sidecar.

Note that your PV `hostPath.path: "/var/data10"` will not contain any data as your stdout does not save here. You mounted this hostPath in the container as "/var/log/containers" will serve no purpose.

Comment: Is there a way to save my container logs inside the /var/log/containers/<..> directory inside the volume hostPath?

Comment: Your motive is to make a copy of your application log. But remind that in real world unlikely you can use hostPath like this, otherwise your application will be tied down to specific node all the time - which is not realistic as node can come and go.

Comment: Thank you for your insight, I had this idea of running a log agent for this scenario but thought there could be an easier way. I agree with you this idea cannot be applied to production level as the volume is mounted to a specific node. Using a different volume type would be best, such as NFS or CSI.

Comment: Also pod can come and go (eg. scale), log files kept on hostPath will scatter across the cluster... later you will still need to consolidate these "distributed" logs to get the correct chronological order. Better off you ingest them centrally right at the beginning. Use of NFS may ease the problem of log files everywhere, but it does not help you to consolidate log message. Example, you can't tell much by just looking at log file name.

Comment: I see I have a lot of research to do regarding what you said, I agree and appreciate your help for this matter. In addition, I am currently working on a centralized solution to capture all my application logs by using a helm chart that consists of Elasticsearch, fluentd and Kibana. I think running a log agent (fluentd) pod for all my nodes would be better than running it as a sidecar for every application pod.

Comment: Official elastic stack the log agent will be Beat (eg. FileBeat, MetricBeat). Of couse Fluentd, FluentBit etc would work but offer less integration capabilities compare to Beat. If you are using cloud managed K8s such as EKS, it's probably easier to use Container Insight and a host of other AWS managed services. But that's up to you. Enjoy!